# Floating text with js onmouseover issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I need some help with this code, I did try it in many ways, but it appears only google chrome (for common users, not the canary, chromium and dev versions) runs it properly... Is there an easyer way to create this code?

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('[target-title]').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
});
```

```css
[target-title]:hover {
  content: attr(target-title);
  font-size: 15em;
  /* optional styling; */
  position: sticky;
  cursor: help;
}

[target-title]:hover::before {
  content: attr(target-title);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -26px;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #1895D4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

[target-title]:hover::after {
  /* content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="wp-block-image zoom target-title">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N2bK9PD/tela-cognitus-edit.png" usemap="#cognitus">
  <map name="cognitus">
    <area target="" tip="menu horizontal" alt="Menu Horizontal" target-title="Menu Horizontal" coords="2,36,1364,93" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Menu em Arvores" target-title="Menu em Arvores" coords="9,105,199,531" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Configurar acesso rápido" target-title="Configurar acesso rápido" coords="1,546,48,587" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Acesso rápido" target-title="Acesso rápido" coords="462,542,952,592" shape="rect">
    <area target="" alt="Barra de informações" target-title="Barra de informações" coords="2,599,1363,619" shape="rect">
  </map>
</figure>
```